# Dygraphs using valueRange with logscale

Tags: dygraphs

I have the following graph, which when displayed with logscale: true and no valueRange specified shows up as expected (Hiding values where log fails).

[logscale with no valueRange](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UD9nX.png)

When I set the valueRange to have a minimum value 0.0001 via the update options:

```
dataPlotHandle.updateOptions({
    valueRange: [.0001, null],
});
```

I get an empty plot and and the following warning:
axis 0 of graph at [Dygraph plot] can't be displayed in log scale for range [-0.0047772577205044495 - 2.1119525929784273]

[logscale with valueRange](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h9hYa.png)

Now this doesn't make sense to me that the range specified in the error message has a min value that is lower than my specified valueRange.  If so what good is specifying the valueRange if it doesn't properly use it?

Comment: You may have found a bug. What happens if you specify a non-`null` largest value with `logscale` set? Does the range for `[.0001, null]` correspond to what you expect if `logscale` is not set?

Comment: Thanks for the reply @danvk .  Specifying a non-null larger value had the same result (an error message with a negative lower range).  Using non logscale it seemed to work as expected.

Comment: Can you link to a demo of this happening, preferably via dygraphs.com/fiddle ?

Comment: Yes, when I find some time I'll try and get something setup for you.

Comment: So as I was putting together the jsfiddle, I determined it's working as expected unless I specify yRangePad option.  You can see that in the jsfiddle.  My understanding was that the yRangePad was for visualization only, and shouldn't effect the range, but maybe my understanding wasn't correct.  Fiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/craigj/85f1ga5e/

Comment: So is this a bug, @danvk?  For now I have a work around.

Comment: Yeah, feel free to file a bug.

Comment: Thanks @danvk, will do.

Comment: Updated fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/85f1ga5e/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I had the same issue and the answer is properly stated above, just rewriting it here so that this question does not seem unanswered:

Make sure the `yRangePad` or `xRangePad` option is not specified. A working example (free to use, written by me) is at https://price.bublina.eu.org/loglog.html